# Securing .ini files from Public Access with NGINX

Tags: security, nginx, server, ini, nginx-config

We are trying to make ini files that are under the web root unable to be accessed by the public. Currently we have the following config

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
        root /var/www/html/WP;
        index index.php index.html index.htm 
index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;        
}
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
    location ~ \.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$ {
      return 404;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log 
off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; 
allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

We have tried many of the solutions here on Stack overflow, but the files are still public.

Comment: I cannot see any reason why your `location` would not match a URI ending with `.ini` - but it will not match `.INI`. Check the access log. Otherwise, use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files. Restart Nginx and clear your browser's cache.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why the ini files are stored in a public web root? Assuming that you're able to 403 the files, I fear this can be subverted by someone who's bored. Why can't the ini files be stored outside the public web root, and then included where necessary? I could be oversimplifying this or misunderstanding something, in which case, **do explain what is incorrect in my logic**.

Comment: The choice of the INI files is chosen by the WordPress structure and the WordFence Plugin

Comment: I had the same issue and I got it working by adding the following line in the nginx conf `    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }`